# how can we pass image directly to a background image in css

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, image

as im having a variable that holds the image, i need to add the image instead of URL in css background image tag, so how to achieve this?
My code now:
.devicewidth{

```
  background:url("image url")}

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {

  table[class=devicewidth] {

    width: 420px!important;

  }

  img[class=banner] {

    width: 400px!important;

    height: 80px!important;

  }

}
```

my image variable: image

this image variable holds the direct image, not any path or url

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using this `var() function` of CSS you can follow below links for reference

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_variables.asp

https://www.javatpoint.com/css-variables

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
:root {
  --image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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');
}
```

then

```
.nav-home {
  background-image: var(--image);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass the image directly without URL we could use the var() function in CSS. The var() function is used to insert the value of a CSS variable. I have provided the link for the further understanding:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_variables.asp

```html
:root {
  --image: url('image url');
}
body { background-color: var(--image); }
```